# openssl verify command fails with "Error loading file..."

Tags: openssl, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate, signing

We are trying to install and verify ssl/smime certifications but we still facing a blocking issue related to openssl verify command.

The following command is applied :

```
# openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CERT-CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b.pem -CRLfile TEST_CLASSE_CRL-1.pem \
  -crl_check -extended_crl -use_deltas certificat_sign.pem
Error loading file CERT-CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b.pem
usage: verify [-verbose] [-CApath path] [-CAfile file] [-purpose purpose] [-crl_check] [-no_alt_chains]
[-attime timestamp] [-engine e] cert1 cert2 ...
recognized usages:

    sslclient       SSL client
    sslserver       SSL server
    nssslserver     Netscape SSL server
    smimesign       S/MIME signing
    smimeencrypt    S/MIME encryption
    crlsign         CRL signing
    any             Any Purpose
    ocsphelper      OCSP helper
    timestampsign   Time Stamp signing*
```

We checked our .p7b file and seems correct:

```
[root@localhost cer]# openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in CERT-CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b -print_certs

subject=/C=FR/O=TEST/OU=TEST STRUCTURE
issuer=/C=FR/O=TEST/OU=TEST STRUCTURE
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Could you please tell us if there are any solution?  Should we modify the file verify.c ? Your help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Use `./CERT-CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b.pem` instead of `CERT-CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b.pem`. Root does not have PWD on its path, IIRC.

Comment: I tried the same command with ./CERT--CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b.pem but the issue persist: Error loading file ./CERT-CPS2ter-2020-TEST.p7b.pem